# finding selected clicked td within a table

Tags: jquery

hi 
my table looks like this

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class='center'>some text</td>
    <td class='center'>some text</td>
    <td class='center'>some text</td>
    <td class='center'>some text</td>
    <td class='action'><a href="www.yahoo.com">go to some other url</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody style='display:none'>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class='center'>some text</td>
    <td class='center'>some text</td>
    <td class='center'>some text</td>
    <td class='center'>some text</td>
    <td class='action'><a href="www.yahoo.com">go to some other url</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody style='display:none'>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

in the first view only the first tbody row is shown and the second tbody row is hidden.
I need that when user is clicking on the first table row the second table row will be displayed/hide.
 I managed to do this with the following code

```
$('tbody').toggle(function(){
 $(this).next('tbody:first').show(); //display the first next tbody         
}
,function (){
 $(this).next('tbody:first').hide();//hide the next tbody
 }
);
```

**now I also need that when the user is clicking on the table cell with the '.action' class this show/hide functionality will not happened and the table cell  link will be preformed**

I tried many options but nothing was working,
I will appreciate if someone could give me some solution to this problem
THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to check in the event handler where the event originated:

```
$('tbody').click(function(event){
     if(!$(event.target).is('td.action a')) {
         var $next =  $(this).next('tbody'); // no need for :first
         $next.toggle(!$next.is(':visible'));
     }
}
```

Reference: [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: thanks it is working with the click  event but not with the toggle event, is there anything that could be done ?

Comment: @winter sun: What do you mean? You should use this instead of `toggle` (I should have made this clearer maybe). Or do you mean that `$next.toggle` is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the `click` event for those cells and call [`e.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent the event from bubbling up to the `<tbody>`:

```
$('.action').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "...click(function(e)..." ?

Comment: i didn't understand where in the  script i need to put it if my function is $('tbody').toggle(function(){
 $(this).next('tbody:first').show(); //display the first next tbody        
}<br>
,function (){<br>
 $(this).next('tbody:first').hide();//hide the next tbody
 }
);